# Find div with class and add HTML5 data attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to find a div with a specific class or id, then adding a custom HTML5 data attribute to it. For example:

Find:

```
<div class="mydv">Hello</div>
```

Then add data-customtype="one" so it becomes

```
<div class="mydv" data-customtype="one">Hello</div>
```

However, the following code does not seem to work:

```
$('.mydv').data('customtype','one');
```

Comment: Did you even tried to do it?

Comment: I've tried $('.mydv').data('customtype','one'); beforehand just like Milind suggest but doesn't seem to work for me.. so thought I'd ask incase there's a different way

Comment: My approach should address your question ;) But to avoid downvotes, you can post the JS code you tried next time.

Comment: Ah... thanks for the attr clarification, that's what I needed. Lesson learn indeed will forsure use jsfiddle from now on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `.data()` function will not add an HTML5 data tag, the data will be saved to the computer's memory instead. The user will have to use `.attr()` in order to add a physical attribute to the tag.

This example will work:

```
 $('.mydv').attr('data-customtype','one');
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use `.data()` to get/set data attributes:

```
 $('.mydv').data('customtype','one');
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R626M/)**

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this simply.

to set the value:

```
$('.mydiv').attr('data-customtype','one');
```

to get the value:

```
$('.mydiv').attr('data-customtype');
```